# ASP.NET MVC dropdownlist value doesn't reflect model's value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have page, which allows me to add interesting places (POI), based on the different predifined categories:

## Models

```
public class POI
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleNor { get; set; }
    public string TitleEng { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionNor { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionEng { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedPhoto { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleNor { get; set; }
    public string TitleEng { get; set; }
}
```

## Create

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Category.Id, ViewBag.Categories as SelectList, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

## Controller

```
List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
        var categoryQry = from d in db.Categories
                          select d;
        categories.AddRange(categoryQry.Distinct());
        ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(categories, "Id", "TitleNor");
        return View(pOI);
```

So when I create a new POI, I get the following state of POI: [image: state POI]

**TitleEng** and **TitleNor** = **null**. So if I will add a new POI object, the **Category** object, only  with the Id, will be added as well.

So **Category** is not mapped as a property, only it's ID filed is.
As I understand one of the solutions is to change POI model and instead of property **Category** have only **CategoryID**. But how can I get a proper mapping, if I don't want to change a model? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your category contain the same column name as model ?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana If you mean "TitleNor" and "TitleEng" - then yes. Both category and POI have such properties. Can it be a problem for mapping?

Comment: Yes i guess, check any spell mistake and if it is correct then specify column name in your **categoryQry** linq query.

Comment: Do you mean this is happening on postback?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana my query works. I can see all items in dropdownlist with realted names. But when I choose one, I get only ID, not a property Category.

Comment: @Tonven, On post back you only get the values you send to the controller. You only send `Category.Id`. You do not have inputs for `Category.TitleNor` and `Category.TitleEng` so they will be null. Not sure why you need them (you would only save the ID value to the database) but if you need it, call the database to get the category with that ID.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried to have 'Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Category, ViewBag.Categories as SelectList, "", new { class = "form-control" })' instead of 'Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Category.Id, ViewBag.Categories as SelectList, "", new {class = "form-control" })'. But then I get the following error _There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Category'._

Comment: You cant use `model=>model.Category` because model.category is a complex object. A `<select>` control only posts back a single value. If you need the category fully populated, then you have to get it again from the database.

Comment: Then what about validation of the ModelState? In my model fields 'Category.TitleEng' and 'Category.TitleNor' are requried. So I return 'Category' based on ID with the following query: 
'Category myCategory = db.Categories.First(i => i.Id == pOI.Category.Id);' pOI.Category = myCategory;'
But still modelState is invalid.

Comment: Your model (view model) should have `public int CategoryID { get; set; }`, not `public Category Category { get; set; }`.

Comment: I can't change a model due to some non - technical circumstances. But still, thanks for the help. I will remove required attribute from the fields in Category. Actually you answered my question, when you said that it is not possible to bind complex object, but only a single one. So if you will post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On post back you only get the values you send to the controller. You only send `Category.Id.` (from the dropdown), but you do not have inputs for `Category.TitleNor` and `Category.TitleEng` so they will be null.

You cannot use `@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Category, ViewBag.Categories as SelectList ...` because `Category` is a complex object and a  control only posts back a single value.

Ideally you should use a view model that contains property `public int CategoryID { get; set; }` for binding to the dropdown.